# Cannot access pawn from attached actor component

Tags: ai, blueprints, unreal-5

I have a pawn blueprint that contains some AI movement code, and looks like this:

[image: Blueprint screenshot]

Now I'm attempting to move that functionality into an actor component so it's easily transferrable to other enemy types.

[image: Blueprint screenshot]

However, I'm having trouble grabbing the pawn itself for the AI Move To.  Get Owner isn't compatible since it specifically wants an Actor Reference and not a Pawn Reference.  Get Pawn Owner doesn't like that 'self' is an Actor Component and not a Pawn Movement Component.

Is there some other, magic function I should be using?  Do I need to rewrite my entire entity as an actor instead of a pawn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out it's possible to cast from an actor to a pawn inside a blueprint.

[image]

That is so useful and I'm sure will solve a lot of problems going forward.